# FireBase log Event once per a device with CallBack

Tags: android, firebase, event-log, firebase-analytics

I want to use FireBase `logEvent` for specific event once for an install.

```
String _HSAREDPREF_EVENT_KEY = "send_event_for_first_run";
        String _FIREBASE_EVENT_KEY = "my_custom_event";
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

    if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean(_HSAREDPREF_EVENT_KEY, false)) {
                  //this means it is sended once
        } else {

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, "1");
        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(_FIREBASE_EVENT_KEY, bundle);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(_HSAREDPREF_EVENT_KEY, true).apply();

    }
```

But when the phone is not connected to Internet this not woks, cause there is no **callback** for `FireBase` `event`! In other hand if I check the Internet connection and if it is exist there is no guaranty for Event that Logged in FireBase server! So how I can handle a specific Event that Guaranties log once per device?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase event names can not contain space. The event that you are logging is using invalid name "bla bla bla". When you log the event it will print an error in the logcat and be ignored. Instead you will receive an "invalid event name" error event with the invalid name as parameter.

Its always a good practice to verify that your Firebase analytics code work before you ship it. To do so you can enable [debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#view_events_in_the_android_studio_debug_log) or use [debug view](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview) to see the events live on Firebase dashboard.

You can enable Firebase Analytics debug logs with this adb commands:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

Comment: you right and I know that we should not use separated string as FireBase event, but I putted "bla bla bla" for example and I correct the question. for ADB command I get Error that there is more than device. can I specify  witch device for enable?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I get Error that there is more then device". Can you post the logcat output? It will help explain the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't comment on an answer thus posting the answer to @Mahdi - mention the android serial in adb command using -s flag in both commands.

```
adb -s $ANDROID_SERIAL logcat -v time -s FA-SVC
```